# Detect if c++11 is enabled in NVCC

Tags: c++11, cuda, nvcc

I would like to detect whether a .cu file is compiled with C++11 support enabled. At the moment i have the following:

```
#if CUDART_VERSION < 7050
  #define C11SUPPORTED 0
#else
  #define C11SUPPORTED 1
#endif
```

However this is not working because even though C++11 is supported, it is not enabled unless `-std=c++11` switch is passed. Is there perhaps something else defined when `-std=c++11` is passed?

***Update***

`nvcc --compiler-options -dM -E -x cu - < /dev/null | grep "__cplus"`

returns

`#define __cplusplus 201402L`

I am using NVCC version V9.1.85. Will checking `__cplusplus` work, even for older NVCC versions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `nvcc` is standard conforming, you should be able to check the value of `__cplusplus` like this

```
#if __cplusplus >= 201103
#define C11SUPPORTED 1
#else
#define C11SUPPORTED 0
#endif
```

Checking the value of `__cplusplus` should work with *any* C++ compiler since at least C++98.

Comment: Yeah i just realized that my compiler defines `__cplusplus` (see updated question). I am not sure though how robust is this when it comes to earlier NVCC versions.

Comment: The earliest C++ standard (i.e. C++98) already defines `__cplusplus`. In fact, it is in use since much longer, although the value might not be just 1 instead of the combination of year and month specified in different standards.

Comment: Oh right. I thought `__cplusplus` was only defined for C++11 + (i updated my question). I could check the value instead of course as you propose in your answer. Not sure though if all nvcc versions (after CUDA 7.5) define `__cplusplus`

Comment: On CUDA 8.0 if I don't pass the `-std=c++11` switch I get `#define __cplusplus 199711L`.  If I do pass it, I get `#define __cplusplus 201103L`